# Can I setup a K8S cluster in VMs with different IP ranges?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cluster

I managed to install a 3-node cluster on VMs within the same network.
But is there a way to install a multi-node K8S cluster on VMs with different IP ranges? (VMs which are not located in the same network)

The reason for this question is the scenario that I have in mind:

I need to deploy a micro-service application (written in Java) with K8S. I made docker images from each service in my application and its working locally.
I plan to have each service to be run in a separate physical location (within different networks)
For this I need a multi-node cluster, but each node will get different IP range. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

if there is a connectivity among the three nodes then i dont see any reason why you cant setup multi node cluster.

note that kubernetes needs the machines to be closer. because lot of calls happen between api server, kubelet, kube-proxy. it would hit cluster and application performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed several tutorials to install a cluster, and in all of them IP range was considered the same. Something like (10.23.1.1 and 10.23.1.2, but not like 10.23.1.1 and 10.144.100.1). So, even though they are close, but each device has different IP (Is this feasible?)

Comment: It seems reasonable for nodes to be close as you said they have lots of communications together. So, if I have a use-case, where I need to connect services which are in different physical places far from each other: Is there a solution upon K8S? Can I make two different cluster and connect them together? (Is multi-clustering possible in K8S?)

Comment: Have you considered using [Federation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/)?